# Fastest way to find roots of second order polynomial upto single decimal point?

Tags: roots

What is fasted way to find roots of second order polynomial up to single decimal point using a program.

Comment: What does 2nd order equation mean, second order polynomial?

Comment: Why not just use the formula you learned in middle-school? It requires a single evaluation of a square root function. That *could* be done faster for purposes of approximation, but it's still pretty damn fast by itself!